# const enum or another

Tags: c++, enums, constants

Please help me. Is this correct?

```
const enum Enum { ENUM1 = 0, ENUM2 = 1} someEnum1 = ENUM1, someEnum2 = ENUM2;
```

I want to

1. ENUM1 and ENUM2 to be const
2. someEnum1 and someEnum2 to be const

Comment: Enum is constant by its [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx). "An enumeration is a user-defined type that consists of a set of named integral **constants** that are known as enumerators."

Comment: It is correct but somewhat unusual.

Comment: have you tried that with your compiler?  Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post complete examples... normally you get an answer yourself before posting.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand that you `ENUM1`and `ENUM2` are not variables so they can't be const because they are values! Compare to

```
 int x = 1;
```

So you would say that 1 is const. Did that make sense?

Your code:

```
 const enum Enum { ENUM1 = 0, ENUM2 = 1} someEnum1 = ENUM1, someEnum2 = ENUM2;
```

is absolutely fine and fulfill your needs. It means you define your enum with your values and create two const variables.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is define the type:

```
enum Enum {ENUM1 = 0, ENUM2 = 1};
```

Then you can proceed with defining your variables:

```
const Enum someEnum1 = (...); // either ENUM1 or ENUM2
const Enum someEnum2 = (...); // either ENUM1 or ENUM2
```

Then you should be done. :)

Comment: No need to split enum definition and variable setting at all.

Comment: Looks like you need to read a C++ tutorial, such as this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/2-1-fundamental-variable-definition-initialization-and-assignment/

Comment: It's not technically necessary to separate an enum/struct/class definition from variable declarations using it but it is a good practice. In my experience, it's not a syntax that is as commonly used in C++ as it was in C.